# ReactJS - check box inside child component NOT maintaining checked stated after expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a list (`<li/>`) of check boxes (`<input/>`) when I check any check box and collapse the lists and expand the list again the checked state is gone from my check box. I am using `state` to set state of the checkbox. How can I maintain this?

The structure is as follows, where the plus sign (+) indicates the expand collapse button:

```
<ul>
  + <li>
        <input>
        <input>
        <input>
        <input>
```

Here, `<ul>`, `<li>`, and `<input>` are created as separate components due to certain additional elements and features that it has.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle example?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/lehaweyiya/edit?js,output Something like this?

Comment: @limelights, yes, your example should also work. But, Im using React.createClass. I hope that does not make any difference. Right? I tried the concept from your example but its still not maintaining the state. The only difference, I found was that you are using React.Component and Im using React.createClass.

Comment: The method of creating the class won't make a difference. How are you collapsing the items? Are you using `display: none` like @limelights, or are you leaving them out of the render altogether (i.e. removing them from the DOM)? If the latter, the state will be reset because you're destroying and re-creating the input.

Comment: @DavidWalsh, I am using https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames and using `className: classNames(cls)`. Is this also resetting the state?

Comment: @DavidWalsh, I tried the other way of using className as well like @ limelights, but still the issue persists.

Comment: Could you please present your code here. Either in the original question itself or on a code snippet site. Without it we can only guess at the problem.